# Store connection string in service configuration for WCF Data Service

Tags: odata, azure-sql-database

I've got one class library project that contains an EF model that points to a SQL Azure database. I also have another Azure WCF Web Role project that contains a WCF Data Service exposing the data in my SQL Azure DB as a OData service. Right now I have the connection string stored in the web.config of the WCF Web Role project.

What I'd like to do is make this a configuration, so move it over to the service configuration files so I can change the connection string if necessary (putting it in the web.config seems shortsighted).

The problem I'm having is how to wire the OData service up to not use the web.config connection string but instead use one from the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(NameofSetting);
```

???

Comment: That wasn't the question... it's how you specify to use a specific connection string programatically.